# Scheduled TFS cleanup of post deployment snapshots?

Tags: tfs, automation, build-process, tfsbuild

Is there any way to schedule a cleanup of post deployment snapshots that get created as part of an automated build-deploy-test workflow?  I'm looking for a way to cleanup any PDS's that either begin with the prefix I specify, or are [@today-7], if possible.

Comment: Do you mean Lab Management snapshots?

Comment: @MrHinsh Yes, Lab Managerment snapshots.  The post deployment snapshots are snapshots created when [this](http://imgur.com/168C0lW) checkbox is selected in the Lab Workflow Parameters.